# How can I remove or rename tabs from the local tasks block?

Tags: navigation, 9, group

[image: local tasks]

I'm using Drupal 9.2.6 with Group module and I want to remove some tabs from local tasks block and rename some of them.

I've created the module and placed above code with *hook_menu_local_actions_alter* and *hook_menu_local_tasks_alter*:

```php
function mymodulename_menu_local_actions_alter(&$local_actions) {
   $local_actions['view.group_members.page_1']['title'] = t('Users');
}


function pacifica_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name) {
   unset($data['tabs'][0]['entity.group_content.collection']);
}
```

The route names where received from webprofiler.

Seems that code doesn't work - Members tab is not renamed to Users, and All entities tab is not hidden. And yes, I've **cleared the caches.**

Could someone, please, point me to the right direction in solving this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to alter local tasks menu titles?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253280/how-to-alter-local-tasks-menu-titles)

Comment: https://gorannikolovski.com/blog/dynamic-local-task-titles-drupal-8-9

Comment: Seems that my problem is that I can't find right variables for particular local task. How can I print all variables used in local tasks block?

Comment: `composer install drupal/devel_kint_extras && drush -y en devel_kint_extras`, then go into your hook and put `ksm($variables);` , then `drush cr` and visit the site and it will print you a nicely formatted var_dump into the messages block which by default is placed on some region on the top of the site.

Comment: oh, man, thank you so much! I've used kint($data); and received the tabs array with all variables!  then unset($data['tabs'][0]['group.content']); worked for me!

Comment: Maybe you could also help me with this:   
 $data['tabs'][0]['views_view:view.group_nodes.page_1']['#link']['url'] = '/node/add/podcasts'; it doesn't work, how custom URL could be provided for existing tab?